# How to get text from paragraghs while preserving a space at the beginning of each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```
<div id="input-content">
  <p>1 2 3</p>
  <p>4 5 6 7</p>
</div>
```

If I do:

```
$("#input-content").text();
```

I get:

```
"1 2 34 5 6 7"
```

How can I do it so I get

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
```

Instead?

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to get texts in an array and then join elements with `' '` as a separator:

```
$('#input-content > p').map(function() {
    return $.text(this);
}).get().join(' ');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y25yg/